# Execute php script when checkbox checked

Tags: php, sql, checkbox, execute

I wanted to do that when my checkbox is checked, a php script whill be executed.
There is my code :

```html
<form action="checkboxes.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" value="dawid" name="chk1"> 4K </input>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></input>
</form>

<?php
   
   $bdd=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=techtronik.pl;charset=utf8", "root");
   $wyszukiwanie = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM procesory ");
   while($wynik = $wyszukiwanie->fetch() )
   {
    echo $wynik ['nazwaproduktu'] . ". ";
   }
   
?>
```

Can someone please help me ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have basic knowledge of html, ajax, and javascript.

In your case you can use ajax call.

1) Checkbox checked

2) Call an ajax

3) Handle ajax and Run php code

4) Return to ajax

5) Success :)

Or just submit form on checkbox check then handle with php.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using jQuery, because it's easy solution for beginner.

Heres the sample jQuery code for your current code:

```
$('input[name=chk1]').click(function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
    $('form').submit();
    //or your ajax request
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you use JavaScript/Ajax, jquery.... And call on check/ on click function

Comment: `Why dont you ajax`! Might be he didn't knew about that. A sample example  would be better in your answer

Comment: True... I'm on the phone so doesn't have a complete example to show... And I give him a way to follow... Sorry if not sufficient :/